# How to serialize fields of super-classes as well as the serializable class

Tags: java, gwt, serialization, gwt-rpc

I have some Serializable Objects which I use with GWT's RPC mechanism.
I decided to make them all sub-class an Object containing common fields such as "id", "revision" etc.
However, I've noticed that GWT does not serialize fields of the super-class, so I just get every super-class field as null on the client-side.

How can I get the super-class fields serialized as well without having to write a CustomFieldSerializer for each and every one of my Serializable classes? Is it possible?

**Example:**

```
public class Super {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

}

public class Sub extends Super implements Serializable {
    private String name;

    // more stuff here
}


// on the client side, inside an AsyncCallback
onSuccess(Sub sub) {
    assert(sub.getId() != null);
}
```

So, when I send this through GWT's RPC mechanism to the client-side, I get a null value in the 'id' field of any instance of Sub. I ensured that in the server, id is not null. I also tried to make the super-class implement Serializable, without luck.

Any advices welcome.

Comment: Please show us a minimal code snippet which reliably demonstrates the problem.

Comment: This is so simple I didn't think that would be needed... but I will add it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For serialize any class in gwt you have to implements Serializable in super class.

To pass a bean you have to fulfill the following requirements (from GWT site):

1.It implements either Java Serializable or GWT IsSerializable interface, either directly, or because it derives from a superclass that does.

2.Its non-final, non-transient instance fields are themselves serializable

3.It has a default (zero argument) constructor with any access modifier (e.g. private Foo(){} will work)

The problem may have different causes.

1.Verify that the class has a default constructor (without arguments)

2.Verify that the class implements Serializable or IsSerializable or implements an Interface that extends Serializable or extends a class that implement Serializable

3.Verify that the class is in a client.* package or …

4.Verify, if the class is not in client.* package, that is compiled in your GWT xml module definition. By default is present. If your class is in another package you have to add it to source. For example if your class is under domain.* you should add it to xml as . Be aware that the class cannot belong to server package!

5.If you are including the class from another GWT project you have to add the inherits to your xml module definition. For example if your class Foo is in the package com.dummy.domain you have to add to the module definition.

6.If you are including the class from another GWT project released as a jar verify that the jar contains also the source code because GWT recompile also the Java source for the classes passed to the Client.

Comment: There was another problem with a field in Super that was stopping me from making it Serializable... after fixing that problem and making Super Serializable, it actually worked...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data in Super to be serialized, you must make it Serializable.